# Limits of integration with a bar

Tags: real-analysis

In Chapter 6 of Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis the author introduces the Riemann-Stieltjes integral using the attached picture which shows integrals integrated on a real interval $[a,b]$.  A partition $P$ is defined as a finite set of weakly increasing points from $a$ to $b$.

[image]

What are the horizontal bars on the limits of integration $a$ and $b$? What do they mean?

Comment: I think those symbols are being defined

Comment: you should have included the rest of the sentence beginning "The left"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the notational definition. He is defining the upper/lower bar integrals to be these sums. He then shows for integrable functions that the upper and lower bar integrals have the same values and then you define this common value to be *the* integral. The notation is chosen just to remind you that one is the uppermost possible value and the other is the lowermost possible value.